# Wanted to partially remove items on x axis while using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph, currency

I am designing a currency converter app and I had an idea to add graphical currency analysis to it.
for this I've started using matplotlib.pyplot . I am taking from date(i.e. date from which graph compares data ) as input from user.And using this data , i am taking real time currency data from certain sources.
But here came the main issue.When i drew the graph the x - axis is really bad.
Ill insert the output i am getting--> graph and a rough code of mine.The main isuue i want to eliminate is that i want only certain parts of x-axis visible.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import requests
x = []
y = []

for i in range(fyear,tyear):
        for j in range(fmonth,tmonth):
            for k in range(fday,tday):
                response = requests.get("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/{}-{}-{}?base={}&symbols{}".format(i,j,k,inp_curr,out_curr))
                data = response.json()
                rate = data['rates'][out_curr]
                y.append(rate)
                x.append("{}/{}/{}".format(j,i,k))

plt.plot(x,y)
```

OBTAINED OUTPUT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nUIf.png)
need answer quickly.....

Answer (score 0):

If for parts you mean to set only few labels along x axis you could use xticks and locator_params. See docs here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import requests

# use some fake data for testing - use your params
fyear = 2019
tyear = 2020
fmonth = 1
tmonth = 13
fday=1
tday=28
inp_curr = "EUR"
out_curr = "GBP"

# init lists
x = []
y = []

for i in range(fyear,tyear):
        for j in range(fmonth,tmonth):
            for k in range(fday,tday):
                response = requests.get("https://api.ratesapi.io/api/{}-{}-{}?base={}&symbols{}".format(i,j,k,inp_curr,out_curr))
                data = response.json()
                rate = data['rates'][out_curr]
                y.append(rate)
                x.append("{}/{}/{}".format(j,i,k))

# create subplot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(20, 11))
# plot image
img = ax.plot(x, y)
# set the total number of x_ticks (the ticks on the x label)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(x)))
# set the labels for each x_tick (actually is x list)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
# set the number of ticks you want to visualize
# you can just select a number i.e. 10 and you will visualize onlu 10 ticks
# in order to visualize, say the first day of each month set this
n = round(len(x)/(tday-fday))
plt.locator_params(axis='x', nbins=n)
# change labels position to oblique
ax.get_figure().autofmt_xdate()

fig.tight_layout()
```

Remember to import numpy! Hope it helps you. Here you can see my output.[image]